# Can't install SignalR client in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Here's my environment:

- Visual Studio 2017 15.1, running on Windows 10, which runs in VM on MacOSX.
- In VS I installed API23 Android SDK.
- On MacOSX: Xamarin Studio 6.3
- Both, XS on Mac and VS on Windows have Xamarin.iOS 10.8.0.175

So, as you can see it's not the latest configuration, BUT it's pretty new. It was the latest around April '17. I have to mention that I installed SignalR a year ago.. so it worked. I don't know why I can't install it now. I'm getting this error during installation from nuget:

Error:

> Could not install package 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client 2.2.0'. You
>   are trying to install this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111', but the package does
>   not contain any assembly references or content files that are
>   compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the
>   package author.           0

EDIT:
Here are targets of my PCL (I'm not sure what the profile is this):

[image]

Does that mean I have to add Silverlight 5.0?

Comment: Use version `2.2.2` (released May 4, 2017), that version will work w/ Profile 111 : https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client/2.2.2

Comment: @SushiHangover I'm not sure if this is the case. I can't install ANY version of SignalR :/

Comment: I just retested 2.2.2 and it installs fine, 2.2.0 does not (results in the error in your question)

Comment: @SushiHangover Hi again, I've checked my profile and it looks good.. I think. I updated screen shot in my question. Can you please take a look? Should I install Silverlight? That's kinda crazy, I removed Silverlight in order to use Cocossharp. It's hard for me to believe, that I need to ADD Silverlight to make SignalR works.